# Is there a way to change default sort type on "unanswered" tab?

Tags: support, feature-request

On the "Unanswered" tab of each tag, the default sort meachnism is by voting.
is there a way to change it? let's say by date? or both (vote and date).

in this way we can avoid reviewing very old questions that the submitter might forgot all about.

Comment: How about using the advanced search options: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20answers%3a0

Comment: @rene: it might help, but is more tedious. why not adding some filter items to the original tab?

Comment: I was just about to ask for the same and found this question. tagging it as a `feature-`request.

Comment: @rene i just took a look at the advanced search, it seems to be a little complicated for a common requirement… i can't find a way to see  the `newest` view of all time unanswered questions of a particular tag...

Comment: @TilwinJoy for which tag? The link I provided didn't give you the results you needed?

Comment: Never mind, i think i got it. previously when i was simply searching with `[java]`  for example, it was taking me to the `active` view which got me confused.